# How do I link to an internal page and click on an element on the linked page with vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I can't figure out how this is done:

I want to link to an internal page with an addEventlistener function. When the linked page loads I want to open a div that is hidden. So something along the line of:

```
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
                  const hiddenDiv = document.getElementById("hidden-div")
                  window.open("/newPage.html" + hiddenDiv.click())
                });
```

I know the code above won't work, but I don't know how it could work, since window.open() ends the execution of the code.

Is there a way to store the function after the page refreshes (without localstorage)? Is there a way to handle it via the url? Or should be done with localstorage?

Comment: You could use cookies: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: Thank for the answer @pokeybit. I'm a bit afraid to use cookies, since people a starting to disable cookies more and more. If I'd use cookies for core-functionalities like this the site won't work for them anymore. What do you guys think?